# CSS won't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I actually have no idea what I should do to fix this CSS.
My friend also have headache to fix this CSS and I need help of you guys to look what is wrong with this CSS, it's work in chrome but don't work in firefox.

Note : Most of CSS there i just copy paste from Internet as I newbies to CSS.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One);

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alike);

body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #555;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

h4, h2 {
    font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
}

.cbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #D75C51;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #b24c45;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(23, 36, 45, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(23,36,45,0.9);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(23, 36, 45, 0.9);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(23,36,45,0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(178, 76, 69, 0.9);
    width: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cbutton:hover {
    background-color: #D45045;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;  
}

.text_input {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0 8px 8px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -ms-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    font-family: Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.text_input:hover {
    border-color: rgba(82,168,236,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
}

.text_input:focus {
    border-color: rgba(82,168,236,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
}

.atas_sekali {
    background: #E2E1E1 url(images/upper_panel_background.png) top left repeat-x;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    right:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    z-index:1001;
}

.content {
  z-index:1;
  padding:100px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#eee;
  position:relative;

}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: .7em; height: .7em; margin: .4em;  }
    50% { width: 1.1em; height: 1.1em; margin: .2em; }
    100% { width: .9em; height: .9em; margin: .3em; }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: .7em; height: .7em; margin: .4em;  }
    50% { width: 1.1em; height: 1.1em; margin: .2em; }
    100% { width: .9em; height: .9em; margin: .3em; }
}

@-ms-keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: .7em; height: .7em; margin: .4em;  }
    50% { width: 1.1em; height: 1.1em; margin: .2em; }
    100% { width: .9em; height: .9em; margin: .3em; }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: .7em; height: .7em; margin: .4em;  }
    50% { width: 1.1em; height: 1.1em; margin: .2em; }
    100% { width: .9em; height: .9em; margin: .3em; }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: .7em; height: .7em; margin: .4em;  }
    50% { width: 1.1em; height: 1.1em; margin: .2em; }
    100% { width: .9em; height: .9em; margin: .3em; }
}

.radio {
    color: #798188;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: .5em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.radio,
.radio span:before {
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: .25s ease;
    -o-transition: .25s ease;
    transition: .25s ease;
}

.radio span {
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    background: #202325;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}

.radio span:before {
    content: '';
    width: .7em;
    height: .7em;
    margin: .4em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.radio:hover span:before {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .9);
}


input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio span:before {
    background-color: #9fd86b;
    width: .9em;
    height: .9em;
    margin: .3em;
    -webkit-animation: pulse .25s;
    -moz-animation:    pulse .25s;
    -o-animation:      pulse .25s;
    animation:         pulse .25s;
}

a:link {
    color: #4a4a4a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: #4a4a4a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    color: #4a4a4a;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
    border:2px solid;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
.container td, .container th {
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #555;
}
.container th {
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.796875) 0px 1px 0px;
    font-family: "Hoefler Text", "Baskerville old face", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.container td {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: table-column;
    min-height: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}

.index td {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.index h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.home {
    background-image: url('images/home.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    float:left
}
```

This table won't show in firefox (only "login" th shown in firefox)

```
<div class='login_main'>
<table class='container'>
<tr>
    <th colspan='2' style='text-align:center;'> Login </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Username : </td><td><input class='text_input' type='text' name='login_username' size=20></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password : </td><td><input class='text_input' type='password' name='login_password' autocomplete='off' size=20></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td align=center colspan=6><button class='cbutton' id='login_button'>Login</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

This is what happen in firefox..

[image]

This is what happen in chrome..

[image]

Comment: what exactly "doesn't work" means? please provide a fiddle and explain where the problem occurs

Comment: and with the above question "what" doesnt work?

Comment: please provide brief description what and where exactly not working..

Comment: i'm sorry, I have edit my question..

Comment: try to remove all `colspan` you defined in the code (and better - don't use `table` for layout) or provide a demo page

Comment: you can try using a reset.css and import it before your this stylesheet. better to create a fiddle in jsfiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rdCSS/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
 .container td {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: table-column;
    min-height: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
```

to

```
 .container td {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    min-height: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your answers is work correctly in firefox and chrome :)

Comment: @Warai: I'm shocked - how did you come to this solution from the somewhat brief description, given the amount of CSS and HTML supplied?